# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pycharm, dyld

When trying to run simple python3 code via pycharm, I get following error

> /Users/slimerski/PycharmProjects/studia/venv/bin/python /Users/slimerski/PycharmProjects/studia/zadania_14.py
>       dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
>   Referenced from: /Users/slimerski/PycharmProjects/studia/venv/bin/python
>   Reason: image not found
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Everything was working until recently I have installed zsh and updated xcode via brew.
I have tried fixing it with `otool -L exefile` but instead I get another error

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: error: 'exefile': No such file or directory.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Try recreating the venv and possible reinstalling the base Python.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. In my case is:

dyld[74260]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python

I checked and the path "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python" does not exist, but "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python" does exist.

Did you find a way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you uninstall that version of python, in this case 3.7... You have to download it again and execute

Comment: Or they have updated to a more recent point release of Python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

I think your environmental variable path may be the problem. If you recently upgraded to MacOS catalina you need to do this:

1, use this command to check what your current variables are set to.

```
$ env
```

mine looks like this: (lookout for the word PATH, as there will be a long list of environmental variable details)

```
PATH=/Users/.../dev/venv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
```

2, what you want to do next is write your path into a ./zshrc file.

```
$ vi ~/.zshrc
```

Paste the PATH you copied earlier into this location. It will be different for everyone.

it should look like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/.../dev/venv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

3, save your file and exit vi.
I assume everyone knows but if you don't:
Press the `ESC` key then type in:-

```
:wq!
```

this will save the file and exit vi

4, activate your file

```
$ . ~/.zshrc
```

your python programs should run without a problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime a shared image is deleted, whether via a brew update or otherwise, your virtualenvs will all break because the python version theyre symlinked to can not longer find a library it was compiled with. (OP obviously knows this.)

If you recompile the installed binary, you *shouldn't* need to touch the virtualenvs.

Assuming your installed version is 3.7.4, and you're maintaining installs using pyenv:

```
pyenv uninstall 3.7.4
pyenv install 3.7.4
```

Note that dev versions of python aren't guaranteed to stay compatible, so you might have a trickier time with those.